# Kafka consumer - uneven partition consuming

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have very strange problem with the kafka consumer (version 2.4.x). So, I have a topic with 4 partitions (messages are written evenly, and producer faster than consumer, so typically I have enough messages in all partitions, when I start to consume).

For the sake of high throughput I need to work with 16 mb chunks of data, that's my code could call poll() multiple times.

When I call poll() multiple times I see (via collected statistics), that consumption of the partitions is uneven. For a 200_000 messages I can have significant difference between two partitions (few times: 20000 vs 90000).

The question 1: how it can be fixed?

The further digging into problem revealed strange hack. If I call method endOffset(partitions) after each call of poll() method the consumption makes even!

The question 2: could someone shed light on the root cause?

Comment: How many consumers are there in the Consumer group?

Comment: There's only one consumer in the consumer group.